# Javascript SVG drawing on canvas failing at event phase 2

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg

I'm trying to embed an SVG on a canvas but I get an error at [event phase 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-AT_TARGET) when the SVG is served from my own domain. The curious thing is if I the same image is hosted on a different server it works fine. The image I'm testing with is the one [here](http://phrogz.net/svg/tiger.svg). Even if I `wget` the image and place it in the image folder I get the same error. However, it does work if I place it in the document with `<object data="/images/tiger.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`, but not if I set the source in javascript and draw on a canvas.

Here is the code I'm using which errors when the image is hosted at my domain:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); };
img.onerror = function(err) { console.log(err); };
img.src = '/images/tiger.svg'; // replacing this with 'http://phrogz.net/svg/tiger.svg' does work
```

Here is the error data from Firebug

```
NONE                          0
defaultPrevented            false
multipleActionsPrevented    false
stopImmediatePropagation    stopImmediatePropagation()  
bubbles                     false
cancelable                  false
eventPhase                    2
isTrusted                   true
timeStamp                   1373387631408000
type                        "error"
```

Comment: can you load other images (e.g. bitmap images) from that folder (on your server)? The folder has read permission set?

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware yes, I can load other images from there and I've also tried after setting permissions to 777 to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path for the image to your server? and what folder do your js script run from (root, /js, ...) ?

Comment: I've tried the absolute path as well and it still hasn't worked. The script is run from the webserver root.

Comment: Is the SVG file being served with the right MIME type?

Comment: I think so, it works fine in an object tag but fails when set as the image source for a javascript `Image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server that hosts the SVG has to send the right headers, and not every server is configured to do so.

There's a good guide here http://kaioa.com/node/45

If you're using apache, you can add an htaccess file to your directory with this code:

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```

This sends the headers to serve SVG and the compressed version, SVGZ.

Hope this helps!